# UNC Virtual Folder

Tags: .net, wcf, api, service, filesystems

I would like to expose some service functionality as a virtual file share to allow conventional applications to use the virtual folder as a real one.

For example, a file path consisting of

`\\\\Server\VirtualShare\File.ext`

means that `VirtualShare` doesn't really exist and only available as long as my service is running. A file access with the virtual share must implicitly use my service.

My question is, whether some API (of samples) exist to expose own virtual file shares. What's about WCF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to write a file system driver to do this. It is fascinating but horrendously difficult and can only be done in C (not even C++). If you are interested check out the [Windows Driver Kit](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/devtools/wdk/default.mspx).

EDIT: You can check out some user mode file system stuff like [Dokan](http://dokan-dev.net/en/) which is interesting but I wouldn't use it in production or [Callback File System](http://www.eldos.com/cbfs/desc.php) a commercial one that I have heard little about so I can't recommend it one way or the other.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need it available from the local machine, checkout [Dokan](http://dokan-dev.net/en/) for writing userland filesystems. .Net wrapper is available as well.

Answer (score 0):

I'll refer you to this, similar question:

[Database query representation impersonating file on Windows share?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24408/database-query-representation-impersonating-file-on-windows-share)

Where I suggested WinFUSE or SAMBA on Linux and FUSE.